# Error by creating a namespace with terraform kubernetes provider

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, provider

I'm struggling to create a namespace with kubernetes provider.

This is the simple terraform code I'm using:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "https://ocp-test-1.srv.xxxx.it:8443"

  username = "admin"
  password =  "admin"
  


  load_config_file = "false"    # when you wish not to load the local config file
}
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "gfexample" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "exampleannotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "labelvalue"
    }

    name = "terraformspace"
  }
}
```

And here is the error:

```
kubernetes_namespace.gfexample: Creating...

Error: namespaces is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create namespaces at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched

  on create_nm.tf line 14, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "gfexample":
  14: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "gfexample" {
```

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Gian Filippo

---

Finally I found the solution:

> client_certificate     = file("/terraform/certificates/admin.crt")
> client_key             = file("/terraform/certificates/admin.key")
> cluster_ca_certificate = file("/terraform/certificates/ca.crt")

This worked fine. I found out the certificates above mentioned under /etc/origin/master (I'm running Openshift 3.11)

Comment: Looking at the kubernetes terraform provider (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/guides/getting-started#provider-setup), you seem to be trying to use HTTP Basic Auth by setting the username and password fields . Are you sure your cluster uses that auth method ? otherwise you need to set the certificate fields

Comment: I exported the certificate connecting to the URL https://ocp-test-1.srv.xxxx.it:8443" via browser and tried:
provider "kubernetes" {
  host = "https://ocp-test-1.srv.xxxx.it:8443"

    client_certificate = file("/terraform/certificates/certificato.cer")
`code`
Now the error is:
    kubernetes_namespace.gfexample2: Creating...

Error: the server is currently unable to handle the request (post namespaces)

  on create_nm.tf line 13, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "gfexample2":
  13: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "gfexample2" {